# Call google chart from partial view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, google-visualization

I'm trying to call google chart from a partial view to a view but the chart is not loading. It was working fine in the view, but when converted to partial view it is not rendering. Anyone please check and help me if anything wrong.

**My View**

```
@model HeathAppDesign.Model.ChartModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ChartTypes').change(function () {


            var selectedID = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/charts/GetChart/4',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    var res = JSON.stringify(result);
                    $('#div-Graph').append(res);
                    alert($('#div-Graph').html());
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
<div>


    <select id="ChartTypes">
        <option id="Chart1" value="0">Projected Annual Cost per Member</option>
        <option id="Chart2" value="1">Projected Annual Cost to Employer by Plan</option>
        <option id="Chart3" value="2">Total Projected Cost</option>
        <option id="Chart4" value="3">Renewal Year PMPM Cost</option>
        <option id="Chart5" value="4">Paid Or Allowed Ratio by Plan</option>
        <option id="Chart6" value="5">Impact of Plan Design Changes on 2017 Costs</option>
        <option id="Chart7" value="6">5 Year Projected Plan Change Impact</option>
        <option id="Chart8" value="7">Impact of Trend Over Time</option>
    </select>
    <div id="div-Graph">

    </div>
</div>
```

**My PartialView**

```
@model IEnumerable<HeathAppDesign.Model.ChartModel>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] }); 


</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        chartsdata = '@Model'
        alert(chartsdata);
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

        function drawStuff() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            data.addColumn('string', '');
            data.addColumn('number', '');

            for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([chartsdata[i].XCoordinates, chartsdata[i].YCoordinates]);
            }

            var options = {
                title: 'Paid/Allowed Ratio by Plan',
                width: 500,
                legend: { position: 'none' },
                trendlines: { 0: {} },
                bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts
                vAxis: { viewWindow: { min: 90, max: 100 }, gridlines: { count: 11} },

                bar: { groupWidth: "20%" }
            };

            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chartdiv'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        };


    });

</script>
<h2>
    Chart5</h2>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 600px; height: 350px; margin: 0 auto;">
</div>
```

**My ActionMethod**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetChart(int id)
        {
            return PartialView("_PaidOrAllowedRatio",
                      objChartService.GetChartCoordinates(ChartTypes.PaidOrAllowedRatioByPlan));
        }
```

**My result is like this**

"\r\n\r\n
\r\n Chart5

\r\n
\r\n
\r\n"
Design table Area

I have multiple charts in the same view and that is why using partial view.

Anyone please help?

Comment: How does your `ChartModel` class definition looks like ?

Comment: public class ChartModel
    {
        public object XCoordinates { get; set; }
        public object YCoordinates { get; set; }

    }

Comment: Follow the answer i posted. That code should work. I just tested in a local project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer, really taken lots of time to fix this. I moved all script references to my view file from my partial view and then called the google.load in view

ie,

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
```

So my view became like below

```
@model HeathAppDesign.Model.ChartModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    **google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });** 

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ChartTypes').change(function () {
            var selectedID = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/charts/GetChart/',
                data: {id:4},
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) {

                    $('#div-Graph').append(result);

                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
<div>


    <select id="ChartTypes">
        <option id="Chart1" value="0">Projected Annual Cost per Member</option>
        <option id="Chart2" value="1">Projected Annual Cost to Employer by Plan</option>
        <option id="Chart3" value="2">Total Projected Cost</option>
        <option id="Chart4" value="3">Renewal Year PMPM Cost</option>
        <option id="Chart5" value="4">Paid Or Allowed Ratio by Plan</option>
        <option id="Chart6" value="5">Impact of Plan Design Changes on 2017 Costs</option>
        <option id="Chart7" value="6">5 Year Projected Plan Change Impact</option>
        <option id="Chart8" value="7">Impact of Trend Over Time</option>
    </select>
    <div id="div-Graph">

    </div>
</div>
<div>
    Design table Area
</div>
```

Thanks everyone for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I see few problems with your code

#### Issue 1

In your partial view, this line

```
var chartsdata = '@Model';
```

When razor executes this code, It generates code like below (you can see this if you check view source of the generated page.(check response tab of your ajax call))

```
var chartsdata = 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[YourNamespace.ChartModel]';
```

This is a **string**. So basically in your `for` loop below you are looping until the length of this string , which is obviously  wrong! Your Model is a collection of `ChartModel`. So you should set the same collection/array as it is to this chartsdata  variable which you can loop through later and use it for adding the data for the graph.

You can use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` with `Html.Raw` to convert your model object to a javascript array.

```
var chartsdata = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
```

This will store an array (of `ChartModel` objects(js version)) to the `chartsdata` variable.

Now your looping code is good

```
for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata.length; i++) {
   data.addRow([chartsdata[i].XCoordinates, chartsdata[i].YCoordinates]);
}
```

#### Issue 2

Next problem is, you are using a wrong variable to update the DOM when you get the ajax call response.

```
success: function (result) {                  
                $('#div-Graph').append(res);   // WHAT IS "res" ?????                  
            }
```

The fix is simple

```
success: function (result) {                  
                $('#div-Graph').append(result);                   
            }
```

Once you fix these issues, the charts will appear on the SELECT element change event ,assuming you do not have any other js errors in the page.

Comment: Thanks Shyju; I have converted the line var chartsdata = '@Model'; to  var chartsdata =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
Also issue 2 is a known one; just tried to stringify the result. :)